# psycopg2 timescale db on connect hangs

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, jupyter-lab, timescaledb

Would anyone have any tips for accessing a time scale db across a LAN with Jupyter labs IPython notebook, the initial connection just hangs most of the time. This is a first time experience for me accessing a postgres db via Python for data analysis purposes.

Hitting the IPython run button for this cell below most of the time it doesn't connect just sits in this mode `[*]` . Or if I am lucky the password prompt pops up to enter my SQL password but most of the time that will hang too. Sometimes rebooting the PC that I am using the psycopg2 helps. Once I can get this initial cell to the connect to the timescale db, I am good its just this initial connection process that I am not used. Any tips for troubleshooting this greatly appreciated.

```
import getpass
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import json



SQL_PASS = getpass.getpass()
SQL_USER = 'my_scripts'
SQL_HOST = '192.168.0.100'
dsn = f'postgresql://{SQL_USER}:{SQL_PASS}@{SQL_HOST}:5432/data_aquisition'
dbengine = create_engine(dsn)
dbconn = psycopg2.connect(host=SQL_HOST, dbname='data_man', user=SQL_USER, password=SQL_PASS)
```

***UPDATE***

On my first jupyter lab cell with just this code below it will hang. The cell will just sit like this `[*]` without the db connection.

```
import getpass
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import json



SQL_PASS = getpass.getpass()
SQL_USER = 'my_scripts'
SQL_HOST = '192.168.0.100'
dsn = f'postgresql://{SQL_USER}:{SQL_PASS}@{SQL_HOST}:5432/data_aquisition'
dbengine = create_engine(dsn)
```

CELL 2 which cant even get too. Its not the `dbconn = psycopg2.connect`

```
def postgres_test():

    try:
        dbconn = psycopg2.connect(host=SQL_HOST, dbname='volttron', user=SQL_USER, password=SQL_PASS)
        dbconn.close()
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Any ideas to try? Any ideas to try with the `try` and `except` also appreciated any thoughts on buttering this exception handing code greatly appreciated.

Comment: Connection attempts hanging is usually a problem with a firewall.

Comment: Ah thanks! ill check into this making sure my firewall is off on this machine

Comment: Would you know how to add in some sort of an `IF` statement to my code to see if there is a live db connection? The firewall is turned off on PC in question.

Comment: Like this information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281875/making-sure-that-psycopg2-database-connection-alive

Comment: Any change someone could comment on my update CODE?

Comment: The firewall in question is probably not on the local machine.  It would be on 192.168.0.100, or on the gateway between them.  If you want the connection attempt to fail rather than hang, you can set `connect_timeout` for  psycopg2.connect

Comment: Why does the first cell in IPython hang in my `UPDATE`? Cell 2 is the `dbconn = psycopg2.connect` where I would think in cell 2 this is where a network connection would be established and potential firewall issues? Any help greatly appreciated not alot of wisdom here...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a cell even is.  Is that a jupyter-lab thing?  In my hands create_engine doesn't establish a connection, that is deferred until the engine is used.  But that is just python, I don't jupyter.

Comment: Yes its like running Python in a web browser where you can run cell by cell chunks of code. Its really nice for data analysis purposes as the web browser portion has great visualization. Each cell you can do something and create a chart. Not like a script where you have to rerun the .py file. I think the hood of IPython there is a lot asyncio stuff going on but not too sure

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `SQL_PASS = getpass.getpass()`

For some reason this `getpass` is hosing things up. Just hard coding the password everything works just fine.